# Applying inter-rater reliability principles

Tags: clustering, agreement-statistics, cohens-kappa

Background: I want to perform a survey/questionnaire for a group of people with very different background and knowledge. Some of them are environmental scientists, anthropologists, and  climate experts. 
The questions within the survey will also have different types e.g. questions about weather, human interaction, etc. 
Obviously, any expert may have more intuition or knowledge to answer questions  related to their expertise.

I want then to perform cluster (tagging) on which clusters a question might be. Cohen kappa statistics may be used to measure agreement between different people.

Can I use a similar concept of Cohen kappa Statistics for this problem? If I want to give more weight towards one kind of expert because of being an expert for that field, how would I do that?

Comment: My advice is not to do anything of the kind. That is a slippery slope best avoided. Whether the experts agree or disagree with the non-experts is part of what you are trying to find out and may be complicated enough at best. Your approach raises too many extra questions of how much to weight, including whether the greater experts deserve even more weight than the lesser experts.  How do you establish independently degree of expertise in any case? Further, I would not put too much reliance on summary statistics, here or anywhere else.